# What's the easiest way to farm gil?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I'm curious about both during the game, and after completion.  What's the quickest, most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a lot of money farming the Cie'rex Cieth at Oerba 400.

With the Fragment-Ability that increases the spawn of rare monsters, you can find him rather easily, and you can kill him in < 10 minuts with the right strategy (which includes clearing his mob as fast as possible).

You get 100k gil per kill, plus up to 3 items (I don't know the english name for them, sorry), which sell for a total of ~50k.

Edit: I think he's called 'Raspatil' in the English version, sorry.

Comment: As an extra note. If you equip 2 Durable collectors catalogs you will get around 180.000 gil per battle. And you can beat the monster within 5 minutes with some practice. 

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LAV8uRdQUg

Answer (score 2):

I would like to know the answer too. For me though, I gained a lot of gil from grinding enemies on repeat. I went to Academia -400- in front of a "red block" where you constantly get into random encounters and just mashed the X button while I watched a movie. Maybe not the most fun way to do it, but it worked. Before I beat the game I had 4 level 99 roles and about 200k gil. I'll let you know if I find a better way.

Comment: Don't forget to sell all your spare materials also for some extra profit.

Comment: @DavidYell - Yeah, I was really thinking not just pure gil drops but if there were any profitable items.

Answer (score 1):

Don Toneberry 18000 Gil per kill, find him at Bresha ruins 100 AF

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Yaschas Massif (110 AF, I think) and fighting the behemoth there. It's the white one, which will give you 2000 xp and 2200 gil per battle.

Answer (score -1):

if you go to acedemia 400 af you can get allot of many from fights(600 gill per kill) and you also get alot of tear of remorses and you can sell those to chocolina.